# how can i send multiple data from one select box to save in a pivot table?

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, pivot-table

I have four models with Many to Many relationships.
`Crew` `Type` `Post`  `Flight`

in `Crew` model:

```
public function crews()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Crew::class,'crew_flight_post_type','flight_id','crew_id')
            ->withPivot(['post_id','type_id']);
    }

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class,'crew_flight_post_type','flight_id','post_id')
            ->withPivot(['crew_id','type_id']);
    }

    public function types()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Type::class,'crew_flight_post_type','flight_id','type_id')
            ->withPivot(['crew_id','post_id']);
    }
```

I created The pivot table `crew_flight_post_type` with this columns:
`crew_id`  `flight_id`  `type_id`  `post_id`  `total_flight_time`

how can i send `post_id` , `flight_id` , `crew_id` , `type_id` by one select box in `create.blade.php` view and save or update this pivot table?

in Store method of `FlightController`

```
 $flight->crews()->attach(request('cap'),['post_id'=>$request->get('?'),'type_id'=>$type_id]);
```

this is my `create.blade.php` view for `Flight` model:

```
<select>
 @foreach($crew as $id => $name)
    <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $name }}</option>
 @endforeach
</select>

 </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

When saving a crew to a `Flight` model (per the example), you need to pass a `Crew` model as the first parameter, then you can pass any pivot values as an associative array in second parameter.

```php
// $flight = Flight::find(?);
// $crew = Crew::find(?);

// attach a Crew model to a Flight model
$flight->crews()->attach($crew,[
    'post_id' => ?,
    'type_id' => ?,
    'total_flight_time' => ?,
]);
```

Also, I assume this was a typo, but you have used both `crew_leg_post_type` and `crew_flight_post_type` in your question above, when I'm guessing these are the same table.

**EDIT: Question in comments.**

> ...how i can send post_id and type_id in my view.

You have several options.

1. You can send them directly since you already have these available as they were used to save the flight/crew relationship.

```php
return view('your-view',['post_id' => ?, 'type_id' => ?]);
```

```php
<div>{{ $post_id }}</div> 
<div>{{ $type_id }}</div>
```

2. Or you can use them through relations.

```php
return view('your-view',compact('flight'));
```

```php
@foreach ($flight->crews as $crew)
    <div>{{ $crew->post_id }}</div> 
    <div>{{ $crew->type_id }}</div>
@endforeach
```

3. Or you can use them through pivot on another relation.

```php
return view('your-view',compact('flight'));
```

```php
@foreach ($flight->types as $type)
    <div>{{ $type->pivot->post_id }}</div> 
@endforeach

@foreach ($flight->posts as $post)
    <div>{{ $post->pivot->type_id }}</div> 
@endforeach
```

Comment: you are right. this was a typo . and table is crew_flight_post_type ,but how i can send post_id and type_id in my view. thank you for your answer

Comment: I have added some edits which may answer your first question.  I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you're asking in the last comment.